# Enforce curly braces for JS switch-cases with ESLint or Prettier

Tags: javascript, eslint, code-formatting, prettier

I'd like to enforce curly braces for switch-cases in JS, possibly with ESLint or Prettier. Do you know of any related config, or if not that, then any other linting or formatting tool?

I tried the ESLint rule `curly` set to `"all"`, but it didn't compain about my curly-less switch-cases.

There is a [switch-case ESLint plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-switch-case), but I haven't found such a rule in its doc, neither in its source code.

**Example**

Wrong:

```js
switch (foo) {
  case "bar":
    return 1;
  case "baz":
    return 2;
  default:
    return 0;
}
```

Correct:

```js
switch (foo) {
  case "bar": {
    return 1;
  }
  case "baz": {
    return 2;
  }
  default: {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `switch-braces` rule in the following eslint custom rules repo seems to be the one you are looking for:
https://github.com/justinanastos/eslint-plugin-justinanastos/blob/master/docs/rules/switch-braces.md

You can give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can try ['no-restricted-syntax' rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) with such [selector](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/selectors).

With verbose output (each non-block child of a case is reported as error):

```
    'no-restricted-syntax': ['error',
      {
        'selector': 'SwitchCase > *.consequent[type!="BlockStatement"]',
        'message': 'Switch cases without blocks are disallowed.'
      },
    ],
```

If `:has` is supported by your parser, you can try this one, but it can have false-positive reports: since child (relative) selectors currently seem to be disallowed in `:has`, descendant non-block `.consequent` nodes may throw.

```
    'no-restricted-syntax': ['error',
      {
        'selector': 'SwitchCase:has(*.consequent[type!="BlockStatement"])',
        'message': 'Switch cases without blocks are disallowed.'
      },
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

*This applies to eslint without plugins.

The `curly` rule does not apply to blocks in switch cases. Unfortunately there is no good rule that does what you need. You can suggest the rule (or edit to curly rule) here https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using unicorn (which I personally can recommend), there is a rule for that:

ESLint Plugin Unicorn - Rule: "Switch case braces":
https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/switch-case-braces.md

It's also in the "recommended" preset since v44: https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/releases/tag/v44.0.0

So, it will automatically be applied, if you have in your .eslintrc.json something like:

```
"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", ... "unicorn"],
"extends": [ ... "plugin:unicorn/recommended"],
```